# RSpec returns empty string in a fairly simple get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test show action in my Shipment controller. To do so I've prepared fairly simple specs:

```
RSpec.describe ShipmentsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    let(:params) { { id: shipment.id, product_id: product.id } }
    let!(:product) { create(:product) }
    let!(:shipment) { create(:shipment, product: product) }

    context 'when params are valid' do
      before { get :show, params: params }

      it 'return valid json' do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(expected_json)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`ShimpentsController.rb`

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product

  attr_reader :shipment

  def show
    @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
    @items = shipment&.grouped_shipment_items
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

When I use postman everything went well - it returns expected json but in the RSpec test I'm getting:

```
response.body
=> ""
```

Comment: What are you using to return json? jbuilder?

Comment: Have you tried running the rspec in debugging mode to check the values. By default rails action will return HTML unless specified to return json. I don't see that code here, can you elaborate on this

Comment: @Clara yes, I'm using jbuilder to return json

Comment: You should really be writing request specs  unless this is legacy code. The use of controller specs is discouraged by both the rails and RSpec teams. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add `render_views` in your controller spec file.

```
RSpec.describe ShipmentsController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  describe 'GET #show' do
    let(:params) { { id: shipment.id, product_id: product.id } }
    let!(:product) { create(:product) }
    let!(:shipment) { create(:shipment, product: product) }

    context 'when params are valid' do
      before { get :show, params: params }

      it 'return valid json' do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(expected_json)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: https://rubyinrails.com/2019/04/11/rails-test-jbuilder-json-response-with-rspec/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not making a request for JSON response with rspec. You can check by putting a breakpoint in your controller action, then checking

```
request.format.json?
```

In order to ask for JSON response from an rspec test, you should add `as: :json` to the end of the request. The request should look like this:

```
get :show, params: params, as: :json
```

Comment: Comment pointing to the change in Rails 5 -> https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1650#issuecomment-504324726